# Date variables being assigned with 'reference' improperly?

Tags: php, date, pointers, reference, variable-assignment

I am experiencing something that seems odd to me, would like a second opinion on it.

It seems like my date variables are applying 'reference' during assignment when they should not be.

Example:

```
$date1 = date_create('2014-09-20');

$date2 = $date1;

date_add($date2,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));

// I would expect this to print "2014-09-20". However it is printing "2014-10-20"
echo date_format($date1,'Y-m-d') . "<br>";

//I would expect this to print "2014-10-20". It does so.
echo date_format($date2,'Y-m-d') . "<br>";
```

Basically, any time I'm changing $date2, it is also changing the value stored in $date1.

Am I insane? Is this proper behavior? Is there something wrong with my compiler? Something in php.ini? Do I just not understand some very simple concept with PHP syntax?

I am using PHP 5.3.28 on IIS 7.5.7600, Windows 7. Accessing the page via Firefox 32 or whatever jacked up current version # they've gotten to now...

I have tried this with "New Datetime"/Add(New DateInterval) method, and with date_create/date_add as in the sample above. Tried creating the vars first and then assigning them.. Same results. Tried adding '&' to the assignment just to see what happens. Same result.

I am having no troubles with the same pattern and using ints:

```
$int1 = 1;

$int2 = $int1;

$int2 = $int2 + 1;

echo "$int1 <br>"; //prints 1

echo "$int2 <br>"; //prints 2
```

It is behaving as if there are references/pointers on the date vars, even though none are specified.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do ref the same object. the following code can give you some insight using debug_zval_dump:

```
<?php
$date1 = date_create('2014-09-20');
$date2 = $date1;
$date3 = date_create('2014-09-20');
echo debug_zval_dump($date1, $date2, $date3);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how then can I:
1) Create a date object
2) Create a second, independent date object and assign it to have the value from Date Object #1
3) Change Date Object #2 independently, such that the value in date object #1 remains unchanged?

What if I do not *want* them to be the same object?

Comment: In this case, you can: $date2 = clone $date1;

Answer (score 1):

No you are not insane, that will be the behavior, if you want a separate object so that it will not reflect, use `clone` instead:

```
$date1 = date_create('2014-09-20');
$date2 = clone $date1; // clone $date1 object

date_add($date2,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));
echo date_format($date1,'Y-m-d') . "<br>"; // 2014-09-20


echo date_format($date2,'Y-m-d') . "<br>"; // 2014-10-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your answers.

Something I want to add to this, having now used your answers to do a bit more reading:

The reason it behaves this way is because DateTime is not a native data type, it is a class. So when we're dealing with a date var, we're really dealing with an instance of a class. This assignment of a pointer to the object, and not a copy of the object, is the behavior for all class objects in PHP.